# what is the time complexity for the LCA in binary tree implemented in Java here

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree, big-o, least-common-ancestor

I have this code to find the `least common Ancestor` of two `nodes` in `binary tree`. I think the time complexity is `O(log n)`. but expert opinions are needed. This code works fairly well on my inputs, but I am not sure if I have tested it exhaustively.

here is the code

```
//LCA of Binary tree
        public static Node LCABT(Node root, int v1, int v2){
            if (root==null)
                return null;
            if (root.data==v1 || root.data==v2){
                return root;
            }
            Node left = LCABT(root.left,v1,v2);
            Node right = LCABT(root.right,v1,v2);

            if(left!=null && right!=null)
                return root;
            else if (left!=null)
                 return left;
            else  return right;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The time complexity of your code is `O(n)`, because you are traversing the whole tree, i.e. you are visiting all its nodes. However, if you don't have BST, but just a binary tree, that is the best you can achieve without having a pointer on a parent node (in that case, build paths from both nodes to root node and return a node that is in both paths). If you have BST, than you can locate both nodes and find least common ancestor in `O(h)`, where h is a height of the tree and that is `O(log n)` if tree is balanced.

Final remark - if you are preparing for a competition or an interview, make sure to take care of corner cases. Your code does not handle the case where one of nodes is not contained in the tree.

Comment: It does the corner case you mentioned, how come you think it does not?

Comment: @user1988876 Well, if there is `v1` in the left part of the tree and `v2` is not in the tree at all, you are returning `v1` regardless of the existence of `v2`. Someone could argue that in that case it should be returned `null`, as well. If both nodes are not contained in the tree, then you are returning `null`, that is correct - I will update my answer.

Comment: that is correct. this means I need to check for the presence of these before I call this method or is there a way I could handle it here?

Comment: @user1988876 No, you can handle it during the process. First thing to do is not to return `left`/`right` unless you are sure that both nodes are in that subtree. How to be sure? Don't return `root` in `if (root.data==v1 || root.data==v2)` line, but go further and check for the presence of other node. In other words, make distinction in your code between "I found a common a common ancestor in the left subtree" and "I found exactly one of the nodes in the  left subtree".

Comment: so if `(root.data==v1)` is true, i would just check for v2 in both subtree and return root if v2 is present else return null; and vice versa  if `(root.data==v2)`

Comment: @user1988876 In that case if one of nodes is in the left subtree and other in the right, your code will fail. It is not that simple problem :) What comes to my mind is to 1) first check the number of your nodes in the left subtree (just count!) 2) if it is `two`, find the LCA in that subtree and return it. 3) check the number of nodes in the right subtree 4) if it is `two`, find the LCA in that subtree and return it 5) if count methods returned `one` for both right and left subtree then return root, otherwise return null. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this runs in `O (n)` because you are passing through the whole graph (i.e. at each node you are going in both directions - right and left).

I would suggest reading [Tarjan's off-line lowest common ancestors algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_off-line_lowest_common_ancestors_algorithm).